# Best way to prevent AVPlayer playing more than one track at a time

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, audiotrack

I'm using AVPlayer to play streaming audio and would like to prevent it from playing more than one audio track at a time. What's the best way to do this? My approach is entirely programmatic -- I don't use the storyboard. When an url is sent to the ViewController (VC, the delegate) it sets up a new instance of the player -- and I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure.  Thanks.

```
 //this routine returns the url from control to the VC (delegate)
  func selectedAudio(_ audioUrl:String?) {
    if let urlString = audioUrl {
      setupPlayer(urlString)
    }
  }

    //single button which toggles between play/pause
  func playOrPauseTouched() {
    if isPlaying  {
      pausePlayer()
    } else {
      playPlayer()
    }
  }

  func playPlayer() {
    if player == nil || selectedTrackName != currentTrackLabel.text{
      if let urlString = selectedAudioUrl {
        setupPlayer(urlString)
        currentTrackLabel.text = "Playing: \(selectedTrackName ?? "")"
      }
    }
    player?.play()
    isPlaying = true
    playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: .normal)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
  }

  func pausePlayer() {
    player?.pause()
    isPlaying = false
    playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: .normal)
  }

  func setupPlayer(_ urlString:String) {
    if let url = URL(string:urlString) {
      player = AVPlayer(url: url)
      let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
      player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
      let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 5) //gives smooth thumb movement w/short clips
      player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in
        let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
        let secondsString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)))
        let minutesString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds / 60))
        self.currentTimeLabel.text = "\(minutesString):\(secondsString)"
        if let duration = self.player?.currentItem?.duration {
          let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
          self.audioSlider.value = Float(seconds / durationSeconds)
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Haven't you tried to stop the `player` before creating a new instance?

Comment: I'm not aware of a stop method for AVPlayer ( although I have seen one for AVAudioPlayer).  But I could be missing something. The only documentation  I am aware of  is in Objective-C instead of Swift, making it difficult for me

Comment: Indeed, there's no stop method. Try if [`pause()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387895-pause) helps to understand if it's a previous `AVPlayer`.

Comment: To help others in the future, I've updated the code to reflect the solution I came to.  I was already using KVO, as Tofaani Kaanudo advised, but needed to improve my equivalent of  "playerDidFinishPlaying" to set "player = nil" once a track finished (and advanced to the next one). Having done that, the "if player == nil" line within playPlayer() is now preventing multiple tracks playing at the same time. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is use `KVO` that will notify you for current state of `AVPlayerItem`.

Means you will get `state` that will help you to identify current item is playing, pushed, buffering or finish to play.

So you should take one `flag` that will handle your current item `state`.

**Ex.**

- Set flag true when item is playing
- Set flag false when item finish to play.
- When you tap on button for play another item then check with flag like `if flag == false` then start playing another item otherwise not.

**Second Way:**

Use `NotificationCenter` like below

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), 
       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
```

and below automatically call when item finish playing

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Item finished playing ")
   // Set flag here 
}
```

And managed flag as same.

Comment: Thank you, your instruction is very clear,  although since I only know a little about KVO,  the places where I have used it have all been just copying others code snippets.  I need to look into it more to learn how to write that code.

Comment: @TonyM - you can use second way